# Asking about a quasicommutative semigroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Honestly, I have been looking for an a **finite Quasicommutative semigroup** by surfing the web, but I could't. May I ask here to give me an example for such this kind of semigroup. I  tried to built one of them by using GAP, but it fails. Thank you so much. I am new to it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. A semigroup is called quasicommutative if for all elements $a,b$ there is some $r \geq 1$ such that $ab=b^r a$. In particular every commutative semigroup is also quasicommutative, and there are lots of examples. Or are you looking for a finite quasicommutative semigroup which is not commutative?

Comment: Dear Martin, I know that and I have found out that the  Clifford (1961) made a methd to constuct them, but I ask for a sample. I though maybe someone gave me an example. In fact, my question is not a problem, but it is asking for a finite quasicommutative semigroup. I have none of them in my hand to work. Sorry if I get the time of all users. Thanks.

Comment: I want it non-commutative.

Comment: I've worked in semigroups for 15 years and never saw this definition. One can easily construct artificial examples but I don't know offhand a natural example that is noncommutative. 

Comment: @Martin and @Sorouh: Is it right the definition written above for quasicommutativity? I have found some online references where it is required $ab=(ba)^r$ instead of $ab=b^r a$.

Comment: @boumol: That notion is used by A.Nagy, but the original equivalent definition is as Matrin noted. In fact, when we use this notation, we intend to find the kern of a group. See this link which is free http://dml.cz/dmlcz/101114. Thanks.

Comment: @Babak: Are you sure these two notions are equivalent? I believe I know how to build a finite semigroup which satisfies $ab=(ba)^3$ for every $a,b$, but which unfortunately does not satisfy your definition of quasicommutativity.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294574/quasicommutative-semigroup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple examples are Hamiltonian groups. Then you can construct Clifford semigroups from them.

Comment: Thanks Boris for the time. I think, I should focus to Clifford's paper again, however it is very old one.

Comment: Babak, in your semigroups all idempotents are central. There are some articles on semigrous with commuting idempotents, e.g. 
C.Ash, Finite semigroups with commuting idempotents, J. of the Australian Math. Society (1987).

Maybe they will be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following is (for me) a bit much for a series of comments.  EDIT:  It is also not
appropriate as an answer.  The fun begins when I alternate quantifiers and turn the
intended property into a semigroup identity.  In an actual quasicommutative
semigroup, $ab=b^3a$ would not say anything about b having torsion.  Even in the
finite semigroup case, there is no justification for saying that all nontrivial powers are
rth powers.  I leave the comedy of inferences for those who like to see how easy and
wrong it can be to deduce something from a single conflation of
(for all)(exists) and (exists)(for all).  END EDIT. It might interest one who wants to construct
an example.

The propety as described by Martin Brandenburg is a semigroup identity that implies
$b^2=b^{r+1}$.  Further, one finds that for $i>1$, $b^i=c^r$ for some $c$ and that $r$th powers
commute with everything in the semigroup.  An attempt at a reduced form for words on
k letters in such a semigroup (this part needs checking before taking seriously) is something
like wp where w is a squarefree word (so w does not have abcabc or similar subwords)
 on some subset S of the k letters and p is possibly 
the empty word and otherwise is an $r$th power involving only powers of the letters not in S.
The subsemigroup of square or higher powers will be commutative.

If the above is correct, I see finite noncommutative examples looking like a small set of extra elements adjoined
to a commutative semigroup, where the square of any extra element lies in the commutative
semigroup.  Not being a semigroup theorist, I sympathize with the original poster and his/her
plight.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.02.05

Comment: After spending two more minutes thinking, I see we can take w to be not only squarefree but of length 1.  Thus either I am very confused, or we have that quasicommutative semigroups form a locally finite variety.  Gerhard "Has Been Very Confused Before" Paseman, 2013.02.05

Comment: I speak hastily, of course.  All of the above is for classes of semigroups which share the same r.  So I not only assume that r is the same for all a and b (minor quibble, as for a finite semigroup I can take R something like product or max of all r), but also every semigroup in the class uses the same r (not so minor).
Gerhard "Now Return To Regular Programming" Paseman, 2013.02.05

Comment:  OK.  I'm in trouble now.  Please help.  ab= b^ra=a^rb^r =ba since rth powers commute.  Or do they?  Gerhard "Shouldn't Be Using Martin's Definition?" Paseman, 2013.02.05

Comment: Perhaps the problem is more basic. I will edit after the light dawns and fills the corners of my cranium.  Gerhard "Quantifier Application Is Not Commutative" Paseman, 2013.02.05